What does it mean to find the rate of change of $y$, when the rate of change of $x$ is already given?
I started to learn calculus just a few days ago, so apologies if anything seems obvious.
I've been having trouble understanding how does finding the rate of change of $y$ work when the rate of change of $x$ is already given? I can solve these type of questions easily, but understanding them has been quite difficult.
The following question has been taken from Sue Pemberton's Cambridge IGCSE™ and O Levels: Additional Mathematics Coursebook (Third Edition), Chapter 12, Exercise 12.7, Question 1:
Variables $x$ and $y$ are connected by the equation $y=x^2-5x$. Given that $x$ increases at a rate of $0.05$ units per second, find the rate of change of $y$ when $x=4$.
So, at first I found $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2x-5$. Then I deduced that since the rate of change of $x$ is $0.05$ units per second, therefore $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=0.05u/s$.
Using Chain Rule;
$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{dx}{dy} × \dfrac{dy}{dt}$.
$\Rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}×\dfrac{dx}{dt}$
$\Rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dt}=(2x-5)(0.05)$
Inputting $x=4$, we get:
$\Rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dt}=(2×4-5)(0.05)$
$\Rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dt}=0.15$
Therefore, $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=0.15u/s$, which does match with the answer key in the book.
Now, I got a question: Why can we just use the chain rule to find the rate of change of $y$, even though only $x$ is given? Why does the rate of change of $y$ not equal to the derivative of $y=x^2-5x$ when $x=4$ (which is $3$)?
Again, I'm a beginner to calculus, so sorry if it seems like a stupid question.


Why does the rate of change of $y$ not equal to the derivative of $y=x^2-5x$ when $x=4$ (which is $3$)?

The rate of change of $~y,~$ with respect to $~x~$ does in fact equal $~3,~$ when $~x = 4.$
So, the problem is ambiguous, because the problem did not specifically ask for the rate of change of $~y,~$ with respect to $~t.$
However, looking at the context of the problem, it is reasonable to assume that this represents the problem composer's intent, because otherwise, it becomes pointless to specify the rate of change of $~x~$ with respect to $~t.$
So, it seems clear that the problem composer's intent was to test your understanding of the chain rule.

Follow up question: 1. If we were to find the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $t$, shouldn't $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=(2t-5)(0.05)$? 2. If this isn't a true related-rates question, then what would an actual related-rates question be like? Could you please provide a link to an example?

No, $~\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} \times \frac{dx}{dt} = (2x - 5) \times (0.05).$  Beyond that, I don't know what the phrase "related-rates question" signifies.
